# How to print all the keys and values together from a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm still a novice in `Python` and currently trying out things with `dictionaries`. I'm having a nested `dictionary` which would look like:

```
nestedDic = {'FROM': {'SOME TEXT FROM': ['CHILD1', 'CHILD2']}}
```

and I was able to print them by iterating through the child nodes.

```
def print_nested(val, nesting = -5):
    if type(val) == dict:
        #print('')
        nesting += 5
        for k in val:
            print(end='')
            print(k)
            print_nested(val[k],nesting)
    else:
        print(val)
```

But the output looks like:

[image]

But the output I need is:

> FROM SOME TEXT FROM CHILD1 CHILD2

Where am I going wrong? Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: You need to add `end=' '` after your print statements for the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should do your work:

```
nestedDict = {'FROM': {'SOME TEXT FROM': ['CHILD1', 'CHILD2']}}

def printDict(inDict):
    print(k,end=" ")
    for k,v in inDict.items():
        if type(v) == dict:
            printDict(v)
        elif type(v) == list:
            for i in v:
                print(i, end=" ")
        else:
            print(v, end=" ")
```

Output:

```
FROM SOME TEXT FROM CHILD1 CHILD2
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vasillis, but then I need the output to be like: **FROM SOME TEXT FROM CHILD1 CHILD2** without any brackets or parentheses or commas.

Comment: Good point @Kulasangar did not notice before. I will try to edit so that it fits your desired output.

Comment: @Kulasangar check `if isinstance(v, list): print(' '.join(v), end=' ')`

Comment: Ok, check the new one, edit it yourself if you feel so.

Comment: @VasilisG. thanks man, it works! :) But a small clarification, how can i make it work for like multiple nested dictionaries? I mean if I have more than one nesting for a child?

Comment: I only tested it for your data, but you can try it for more complicated structures and let me know how it works.

Comment: Sure, will ping you back. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `print(end=' '); print(k)`, you want `print(k, end=' ')`. Changing kwargs like that in a call to a function doesn't leave them set the next time you call it.

Comment: Thanks, @Moxieball, and I"m getting the output as **FROM SOME TEXT FROM ['CHILD1', 'CHILD2']**
But I need the output without any brackets or parentheses:
**FROM SOME TEXT FROM CHILD1 CHILD2**

Comment: You mean, if I don't need the brackets? Because I don't need the brackets, parantheses or commas. I just need it as a plain text.

Comment: @Kulasangar sorry, I misunderstood your question. If you don't need the brackets, then you're gonna need to join the list yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
def printNestedDict(d: dict):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if (isinstance(v, dict)):
            print(k, end = " ")
            printNestedDict(v)
            continue

        if (any(isinstance(v, t) for t in [tuple, list])):
            print(k, *v, sep = " ", end = " ")
            continue
        print(k, v, sep = " ", end = " ")
```

Does exactly as you expected, checks for collections and will output each one.

Answer (score 1):

**@Kulasangar**, your question is very interesting and nice. I thought to solve your problem using recursion.

It works fine with your provided nested input dictionary and many other nested input dictionary containing other data structures like **list**, **tuple**, **set**, **int**, **float** etc.

I thought what if you will have **int**, **float**, **complex**, **long**, **tuple** as keys and what if you will have any iterable like **set**, **list**, **tuple** as items in the corresponding value.

> **set** and **dictionary** are unordered types so it is better if you will limit their length to 1 item. That is why I have limited their length to 1 to get the words of the final string in sequence.

Eg. for the below **INPUT** dictionary.

```
nestedDic = {
    ('DATA', 'ANALYSIS'): {'IS': {'VERY': {'VERY': ['IMPORTANT.']}}},
    4+4j: ['IS', ('A', 'Complex', 'number.')],
    3.14: {
        'IS': {'VALUE': {
                'OF PI': {
                    '(A MATHEMATICAL': ['CONSTANT).']
                }
            }
        }
    },
    1729: ['IS', 'KNOWN', ('AS', ('RAMANUJAN NUMBER.'))], # sets can only contain immutable values
    'I AM RISHIKESH': {
        'AGRAWANI.': 'A GREAT FAN',
        ('OF', 'PYTHON'): (' AND MATHEMATICS.', {'I WAS BORN ON'}), 
        1992: 'AND I LIKE THIS YEAR.'
    }
}
```

You will expect the below string as **OUTPUT**.

```
DATA ANALYSIS IS VERY VERY IMPORTANT. (4+4j) IS A Complex number. 3.14 IS VALUE OF PI (A MATHEMATICAL CONSTANT). 1729 IS KNOWN AS RAMANUJAN NUMBER. I AM RISHIKESH AGRAWANI. A GREAT FAN OF PYTHON AND MATHEMATICS. I WAS BORN ON 1992 AND I LIKE THIS YEAR.
```

Now, please have a look at the below Python code. Here I have 2 recursive functions.

> **get_string()** works on **list**, **tuple**, and **set**. It also works if dictionary's key is a **tuple**.
>
> **get_string_from_nested_dict()** recursively creates a string. If it finds any key as **tuple** then it calls another recursive function **get_string()** to get exact string of words (instead of using the tuple itself).

```
def get_string(l):
    s = ''
    for elem in l:
        if type(elem) is str:
            s += elem + ' '
        elif type(elem) is tuple or type(elem) is list or type(elem) is set: # tuple, list, set
            s += get_string(elem) + ' '
        else: # int,float, complex, long
            s += str(s) + ' '

    return s.strip() # Remove leading or trailing white spaces

def get_string_from_nested_dict(nestedDic):
    s = ''

    for key in nestedDic:
        if s is str:
            s += key + ' '
        elif type(key) is tuple:
            s += get_string(key) + ' '
        else: # int, complex, float, long
            s += str(key) + ' '

        item = nestedDic[key]

        if type(item) is dict: # dict
            s += get_string_from_nested_dict(nestedDic[key]) + ' '
        elif type(item) is tuple or type(item) is list or type(item) is set: # list, tuple, set
            s2 = get_string(item)
            s += s2 + ' '
        else: # int, float, comples, long
            s += str(item) + ' '

    return s.strip() # Remove leading or trailing white spaces


# Start
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # *** TEST CASE 1 ***
    nestedDic = {'FROM': {'SOME TEXT FROM': ['CHILD1', 'CHILD2']}}
    s = get_string_from_nested_dict(nestedDic)
    print(s, '\n') # FROM SOME TEXT FROM CHILD1 CHILD2

    # *** TEST CASE 2 ***
    nestedDic2 = {'HELLO,': {
        'IT IS': ['VERY', {'NICE', 'PROGRAM.'}],
        'PYTHON': {'IS', 'SUPER.'},
        'YOU': ('CAN USE IT', 'FOR', ['DATA SCIENCE.'])
        }
    }
    s2 = get_string_from_nested_dict(nestedDic2)
    print(s2, '\n')

    # *** TEST CASE 3 ***
    nestedDic3 = {
        ('DATA', 'ANALYSIS'): {'IS': {'VERY': {'VERY': ['IMPORTANT.']}}},
        4+4j: ['IS', ('A', 'Complex', 'number.')],
        3.14: {
            'IS': {'VALUE': {
                    'OF PI': {
                        '(A MATHEMATICAL': ['CONSTANT).']
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        1729: ['IS', 'KNOWN', ('AS', ('RAMANUJAN NUMBER.'))], # sets can only contain immutable values
        'I AM RISHIKESH': {
            'AGRAWANI.': 'A GREAT FAN',
            ('OF', 'PYTHON'): (' AND MATHEMATICS.', {'I WAS BORN ON'}), 
            1992: 'AND I LIKE THIS YEAR.'
        }
    }
    s3 = get_string_from_nested_dict(nestedDic3)
    print(s3)
```

#### Output »

[image]

Comment: this looks impressive and should be valid for child nodes which are above one level of depth. Kudos for putting this up.

Comment: Thanks **@Kulasangar** for your question. It was really awesome. These 2 recursive functions can be further improved to support other data types if you wish for **OrderedDicitem**, **defaultdict**, **frozenset** etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution but valid only in cases like yours:

```
output = []
def print_nested(val):
    if type(val) == dict:
        for k, v in val.items():
            output.append(k)
            print_nested(v)
    elif type(val) == list:
        for k in val: 
            output.append(k)
            print_nested(k)


nestedDic = {'FROM': {'SOME TEXT FROM': ['CHILD1', 'CHILD']}}
print_nested(nestedDic)
output = " ".join(output)
print(output)
```